# Proving the Epsilon Trick

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove: If real numbers $a$ and $b$ satisfy the inequality $a \leq b+\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$, then $a \leq b$.

Comment: *Proving the Epsilon Trick*

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, I'm voting to close this question  because you show no effort of your own. If you edit the question to tell us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help. Please use mathjax to write mathematics (as @BrianTung has done for you): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: To add onto Ethan's comment: Where did you encounter this?  In a textbook?  Are you taking a course?  What specific analysis topic are you studying at the moment?  What principles have you learned that we could help you bring to bear on this problem?  Also: You should learn to enter your problem in MathJax.

Answer (score 4):

If $a>b$ then there is $n > 1/(a-b)$. Take $\epsilon=(1/n) \lt (a-b)$. Therefore, $b+\epsilon < a$. Contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I'm glad you want to help people. But with a poorly written question like this one it's best to find out what kind of answer is likely to help before jumping in to provide one. (See the comments.)

Comment: @EthanBolker I found the question perfectly written. In fact, I understood it just fine. It is precise, and succinct.

Comment: I agree that it's clear. I could have chosen a better phrase than "poorly written" to say that I thought it better to wait to see what the OP managed his/herself before providing an answer.